# runing an Azure DevOps pipeline for a Talend ESB project maven error

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, talend

I'm trying to run an Azure DevOps pipeline for talend ESB project but I got this error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project routines: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example.local_project.code:routines:jar:7.3.1: Could not find artifact org.talend.libraries:crypto-utils:jar:5.2.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :routines
```

Any help please.

Comment: yes it help me to solve my problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message log, this error generally occurs when Maven could not download dependencies. Possible causes for this error are:

1. The POM misses the declaration of the  which hosts the
   artifact.
2. The repository you have configured requires authentication and Maven
   failed to provide the correct credentials to the server. In this
   case, make sure your ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml contains a
    declaration whose  matches the  of the remote
   repository to use. See the [Maven Settings Reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) for more
   details.
3. The remote repository in question uses SSL and the JVM running Maven
   does not trust the certificate of the server.
4. There is a general network problem that prevents Maven from
   accessing any remote repository, e.g. a missing proxy configuration.
5. You have configured Maven to perform strict checksum validation and
   the files to download got corrupted.
6. Maven failed to save the files to your local repository, see
   [LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException) for more details.

You can refer to this [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException) to troubleshoot.